# Can I get an iPad unlocked?

Tags: ipad

I am being offered an iPad at a really good price but the seller says he can't remember his iCloud information so the tablet is locked. Is there a way to get this corrected?

Comment: SCAM.....SCAM...

Comment: The owner of the iPad needs to contact Apple to get control of their iCloud account. Buying such an iPad is highly likely to be stolen property....

Answer (score 0):

Short => So far, it's not possible at the Moment.

There are some Fake Unlocks for an iCloud Activation Bypass but if I'm correct - this are not working solutions.

You have to be careful, if the Seller doesn't even know the iCloud/ApplID Mail (normally you don't forget a e-Mail uh?) - otherwise he would be able to reset Password via [Apple](https://appleid.apple.com/)

Note: Not sure if an iCloud unlock would even be legal in every country!